# How to create and manage a multi tab Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, multiple-instances, android-navigation

I'm trying to add multi tab functionality (browser like) to an already existent app, a mobile client for [Netbox](https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox), and the goal is to implement a multi tab environment to manage more items at the same time.

This app is written in Kotlin, using android navigation (single activity) and MVVM.

Searching on the internet I didn't find a reliable solution, and I came up with an idea based on managing multiple instances of the main activity, because creating multiple instances it's quite simple.

If this solution can be considered good, I need to find a way to manage various instances to be able to switch between them, maybe with a navigation drawer.

If this solution it's unsuitable, every other idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

See viewpager or viewpager2 ( Recommended ). https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2?hl=en